# Testing an Apache Kafka Integration within a Spring Boot Application with JUnit 5 and EmbeddedKafkaBroker

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-test

I have a simple producer class defined as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyKafkaProducer {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyKafkaProducer.class);

    @Value("${my.kafka.producer.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendDataToKafka(@RequestParam String data) {

        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> listenableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, data);

        listenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                log.info("Sent data {}", result.getProducerRecord().value());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                log.error("Unable to send data {} due to: {}", data, ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is work-in-progress test class:

```java
@EmbeddedKafka
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyKafkaProducerTest {

    private static final String TOPIC = "device";

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    @Autowired
    private MyKafkaProducer producer;

    BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records;

    KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container;

    @BeforeAll
    void setUp() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("consumer", "false", embeddedKafkaBroker));
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(TOPIC);
        container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, containerProperties);
        records = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        container.setupMessageListener((MessageListener<String, String>) records::add);
        container.start();
        ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, embeddedKafkaBroker.getPartitionsPerTopic());
    }

    @AfterAll
    void tearDown() {
        container.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIfWorks() throws InterruptedException {
        // Arrange
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafkaBroker));
        Producer<String, String> producer = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer()).createProducer();

        // Act
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, "my-aggregate-id", "{\"event\":\"Test Event\"}"));
        producer.flush();

        // Assert
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> singleRecord = records.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        assertThat(singleRecord).isNotNull();
        assertThat(singleRecord.key()).isEqualTo("my-aggregate-id");
        assertThat(singleRecord.value()).isEqualTo("{\"event\":\"Test Event\"}");
    }
```

The problem is that the test creates a default producer:

```java
Producer<String, String> producer = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer()).createProducer();
```

How can I use my own producer, `MyKafkaProducer`, and call its `sendDataToKafka` method? How and what can we test in this case?

The source code could be found [here](https://github.com/belgoros/kafka-producer-consumer-basics).
The branch with a work-in-progress test is [here](https://github.com/belgoros/kafka-producer-consumer-basics/tree/test_producer).
Thank you.

Comment: You need to show how you are configuring the `KafkaTemplate` and its producer factory in your producer. Bottom line is you have to coerce it to use the embedded kafka broker addresses, but we can't help with that unless you show how you are configuring it.

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for the response. The class `MyKafkaProducer` is as it is posted above, nothing more.

Comment: Right but what about the `KafkaTemplate` that is wired into it; where is that configured?

Comment: I've just pushed the latest modifications to the GitHub repo and updated the post with its links.

Comment: @GaryRussell, as for `KafkaTemplate`, no, it is just injected into the producer class with `@Autowired` annotation. Or I'm missing smth?

Comment: You should have indicated that you are using Spring Boot - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

So it's a Spring Boot application and you are using the auto-configured `KafkaTemplate`.

To override the `bootstrap-servers` to use the embedded kafka broker, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#kafka-testing-embeddedkafka-annotation

```java
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = "someTopic",
        bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
```

You can then call your producer from the test case.

Comment: I added the above annotation, as well as declared `private MyKafkaProducer myKafkaProducer;` annotated with `@Autowired`. Then created a simple test method that checks it: `assertTrue(myKafkaProducer != null);`. It failed with `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.codeaches.kafka.basics.MyKafkaProducer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: Annotation as follows: `@EmbeddedKafka(topics = "device",
        bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers")`. The test fails even if I remove the new test method and keep the autowired `private MyKafkaProducer myKafkaProducer;` declaration.

Comment: You need to add @SpringBootTest to your test case. Or add a `@Bean` declaration for your producer in your test context.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot it worked and when calling the producer `myKafkaProducer.sendDataToKafka("Hello D-1")`,  it displayed `Sent data Hello D-1` in the console log, yay!

Comment: Hmm, but when checking the records with: `ConsumerRecord<String, String> singleRecord = records.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        assertThat(singleRecord).isNotNull();`, it fails :(. Why so?

Comment: Maybe 100ms is not enough time? I see you are waiting for the partitions to be assigned before sending so it shouldn't be a problem with `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` being the default `latest`. Check the logs to make sure the producer and consumer are connected to the same broker. Use the command line tools `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` and `kafka-console-consumer` or `kafdrop` to dig around to see what's going on.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the connection to the broker is not available: `Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`. The gist of full stacktrace is available [here](https://gist.github.com/belgoros/de4265c66808f30453fb8103b202fcc7)

Comment: There's something wrong with your set up - the admin client is connecting to the embedded broker `bootstrap.servers = [127.0.0.1:55978]` but the consumer in `My-Consumer-Group` is attempting to connect to `bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]`. Your test consumer and producer are connecting to the embedded broker. So I think that error is a red herring (but we need to figure out what that consumer is and why it is connecting to the wrong broker).

Comment: You are consuming from a topic `device` - `consumer: partitions assigned: [device-0, device-1]` but it looks like you are publishing to a topic called `My-Test-Topic` - `Auto creation of topic My-Test-Topic with 2 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, - I declared in `application.yml` the topic value and forgot about that. After changing it to be the same as in the test class (`device`), it worked like a charm! Thank you so mush:)

Comment: You can override `application.yml` properties by adding a `@TestPropertySource` to your test class.