# Exception while testing Spring Kafka error handler for @KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am trying to test my error handler defined in the containerlistenerfactory which is being used by @KafkaListener.

I have different retry counts based of different exception throw by the listener which i want to test is working correctly. But i am getting a illegal state exception after the first time it throws an exception and goes to the error handler, so it is not attempting the retries in the test that i am writing.
The same code works in the actual setup.

Here is the exception that i am getting.

Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException

I expect the test to retry 10 times and then prints the message in the recovery. But it is not retrying as the errorhandler is throwing an illegal state exception.

Can someone please suggest?

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public  class Config {

    public static boolean seekPerformed;
    
    public static int retries;
    
    private Integer retryCount=10;

    private Integer RetryCount2=5;
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;
    
    @Spy
    private errorCodes errorCodes;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Anky>kafkaListenerContainerFactory(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Anky>factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(embeddedKafka));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
            System.out.println(
                    "RetryPolicy** limit has been exceeded! You should really handle this better." + record.key());
        });
        errorHandler.setBackOffFunction((record, exception) -> {
            retries++;
            seekPerformed = true;
            int maxRetryCount = retryCount+ retryCount2;
            Anky msg = (Anky) record.value();

            if (msg.getErrorCode.equals(getExceptionA())) {
                return new FixedBackOff(0L,Long.valueOf(retryCount));
            }
            else {
                return new FixedBackOff(0L,Long.valueOf(retryCount2));
            }

        });
        errorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        //errorHandler.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Anky> consumerFactory(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        //return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(embeddedKafka));
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(embeddedKafka), new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(EdealsMessage.class, false));
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokerAddress(0).toString());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "retry-grp");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        //props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, new StringDeserializer());
        //props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, new JsonDeserializer<>(EdealsMessage.class, false));
        return props;
    }


    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> testProducerFactory(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokerAddress(0).toString());
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> testKafkaTemplate(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(testProducerFactory(embeddedKafka));
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic("sr1");
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "sr1", groupId = "retry-grp",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen1(ConsumerRecord<String, Anky> record,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT) int delivery) throws AppException{

    
        try {
            throw new AppException(//this is our custom exception in the application);
        }
        catch(AppException se) {
            if(record.value().getNewErrorCode().equals(se.getErrorCode())) {
                System.out.println("are you here?");
                throw se;
            }
    }

}

@EnableKafka
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@EmbeddedKafka(
        partitions = 1, 
        controlledShutdown = true, topics = {"sr1"},
        brokerProperties = {
            "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:3333", 
            "port=3333"
    })
public class KafkaRetryTest {

    @Autowired
    private Config config;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template;
    
    @Autowired
    KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
    
    @Autowired
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker kafkaEmbedded;
    
    
    @Spy
    private ErrorCodes errorCodes;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception,SystemException {
      for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
        ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer, 
        kafkaEmbedded.getPartitionsPerTopic()
        );
      }
    }

    @Test
    public void testStatefulRetry() throws Exception {
        Anky msg = new Anky();
        msg.setNewErrorCode(errorCodes.getExceptionA());
        this.template.send("sr1","3323800",msg);
        assertThat(this.config.seekPerformed).isTrue();
        System.out.println("******"+this.config.retries);
}   
}
```

*******Updated code, i am unable to use  bootstrapServersProperty ="spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers on EmbeddedKafka as it keeps trying to go to localhost:9092 and timesout

Here is my config for the test file

```
@EnableKafka
@SpringBootTest(classes=MyConsumer.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@EmbeddedKafka(
    partitions = 1, 
     topics = {"test_topic"}
             , bootstrapServersProperty ="spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers"
    )
public class KafkaConsumerTest {
}
```

AppConfig*** (bootstrapaddress is read from the properties file)

```
@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Anky> consumerFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommit);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Anky.class, false));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the full stack trace for the `IllegalStateException`.

> Seek to current after exception

That's normal; you can suppress that by setting the log level.

This works as expected for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So64780994Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64780994Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so64780994", topics = "so64780994")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so64780994").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorHandler handler() {
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((rec, ex) -> {
            System.out.println("Retries exhausted:" + rec);
        });
        eh.setBackOffFunction((rec, ex) -> {
            return new FixedBackOff(0L, 8);
        });
        eh.setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        return eh;
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so64780994", "foo");
    }

}
```

```
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:04.836  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:05.334  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:05.836  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:06.338  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:06.843  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:07.347  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:07.856  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
2020-11-11 09:20:08.361  INFO 65759 --- [o64780994-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so64780994-1, groupId=so64780994] Seeking to offset 2 for partition so64780994-0
foo
Retries exhausted:ConsumerRecord(topic = so64780994, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 2, CreateTime = 1605104404708, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 3, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = foo)
```

Comment: For me also it works with the actual kafka cluster setup. But when i am trying to create it with a test only then it is failing. After it reaches the error handler, it doesnot go back to the listener again rather throws IllegalStateException

Comment: Without a stack trace, I can't help you.

Comment: Weirdly it works now without any changes. But one more question... since my test is putting a message to the topic and after that consumer gets called on its own... is there a way my test can know when the listener is finished? Currently i am doing a thread.sleep so that verify call from my test runs after consumer is done but that is not a confirmed way that listener is finished.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do it; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518844/how-to-check-if-kafkalistener-was-invoked-in-integration-test/58523485#58523485) and the one it links to.

Comment: Thankyou i have one more question.... I have two different test classes annotated with @EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, controlledShutdown = true, topics = { "abc" }, brokerProperties = {
  "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:3333", "port=3333" }) . Individually these classes work fine... but in the maven build one of the test class fails complaining that port 3333 is already in use... what can i do to fix that?

Comment: It's best not to do that; leave the port 0 (default) and the operating system will select an available port; then configure the annotation to replace your `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` property - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596438/testing-an-apache-kafka-integration-within-a-spring-boot-application-with-junit/63600523#63600523). You should also add `@DirtiesContext` to the test class so that the broker is shut down when the test ends.

Comment: its not working for me... i am getting a timeout exception when i set it like this. What should i do? - @DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = { "sr1" }, bootstrapServersProperty  ="spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")

Comment: is it okay if i keep the port in both classes to 3333 but add @DirtiesContext?

Comment: In the logs i see this that it keeps trying to connect to localhost:9092 and goes to timeout if am doing @DirtiesContext @EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = { "sr1" }, bootstrapServersProperty ="spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")

Comment: It is a bit odd that you reference the embedded Kafka broker in your main Config class. You seem to be bypassing all the boot auto configuration goodness. See my answer. It is much simpler than your code. It is not obvious why it would try to connect to 9092. If you post the whole project someplace I can take a look tomorrow. But I recommend simplifying your config at take advantage of Boot’s goodness.

Comment: the config is not main config in my app... i have created this config only for the testing files.. and creating the same producer and consumer beans as defined in the main config... with the embedded kafka bootstrap address...because the actual main config points to the bootstrap address in the real cluster... but in the test config i am trying override the same beans and point them to embedded kafka address....  is there any other way so that those beans while testing can point to embedded kafka bootstrap server?

Comment: ohh i got what you saying now... will remove this config and test... thankyou

Comment: i posted the updated code... can you please take a look? it still keeps trying to go to 9092 and timesout if i dont explicitly set that with @EmbeddedKafka

Comment: nevermind... i was finally able to make it work using @SpringBootTest(properties = {
  "kafka.bootstrapAddress=${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}" })